# Estimating the best restore time from saved backups in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, backup, restore, recovery

I am looking for guidance and any advice on how to estimate the restore time for SQL Server databases once copied locally to the server.

This is just to layout a strategy what will happen if in future my SQL Server gets compromised. We are on to the point where SQL Server is made available and it's time to restore those databases. Assuming backups are valid, I am trying to find a way if we can actually tell or do a best estimation to give timelines for those backups to  get restored from backups.

I've found RTOWorstCaseMinutes in https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/12/check-your-sql-server-backup-performance-safety-with-sp_blitzbackups/ but not sure if it really means what I am looking for.

If there is a better way on approaching this please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

If you use SSMS to restore a backup, it gives a progress bar with percentage complete, which you can roughly estimate the overall runtime from. For example:

[image: SSMS Restore Database Progress]
Referenced from [SQL Server Best Practices: Monitoring Backup and Restore Progress](https://alibaba-cloud.medium.com/sql-server-best-practices-monitoring-backup-and-restore-progress-2ff10a7a43f8)

Alternatively, I've generally found [Adam Machanic's `sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com/) is able to pull the progress metrics from the appropriate system catalog entities for backup operations. It gives an estimated time remaining column for such operations in addition to the total runtime so far.

Finally, if you script the restore of your backups instead of using the SSMS Restore Database UI, the Messages tab will also give you updated information on the restore progress.

Regarding your follow-up clarification in the comments, I don't think it's possible to *accurately* predict how long a restore will take *in practice* before actually running it since it'll be dependent on the hardware behind the server you're restoring to. This will mostly  be bound by the I/O of the disk, but also the CPU will be relevant for decompressing the backup, and of course the overall busyness of the server at the time of the restore comes into play as well.

Your best bet is to routinely restore your backups (which you should be doing anyway to verify they're not corrupt) and create a baseline of how long they're normally taking to restore.

Comment: thanks but this is applicable only once i start restoring from backups. Without actually doing i was thinking if we can predict

Comment: @Newbie-DBA Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Thanks , i found https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/12/check-your-sql-server-backup-performance-safety-with-sp_blitzbackups/ and there is a column 'RTOWorstCaseMinutes'. Should this be close ?

Comment: @Newbie-DBA Good find! It's interesting they actually devised a formula, but they even disclaim "*Technically, this isn’t accurate because your restores could take longer than the backups*". So I don't think it's safe it will always be close. I wouldn't discredit the information it provides either but I still think your best bet is to routinely restore your backups to create a baseline and to ensure your backups are not corrupt.

Comment: I agree to do it in perf but just wanted to give a headsup number to management as starting all this process is very lengthy here :)

Comment: Also note that the restore process does recovery as part of the restore. this isn't in the backup, so this is extra work. Many of us has seen cases where the process is at 100%, but the restore still keep going for an hour or two (being the recovery process).

Comment: If you script the restore, you view the progress on the messages tab, as well.

Comment: @BrendanMcCaffrey Good point! 

Answer (score 1):

RTOWorstCaseMinutes from the First Responder Kit is going to be your best bet. There is no true way to predict how long it will take to restore a backup, until you actually try to restore it and record how long it takes.

All RTOWorstCaseMinutes is really doing to looking at how long it took to take the most recent backups that would be required for a restore. It’s an educated guess that if it took 4 hours to take a full and several log backups, it will likely take a similar amount of time to restore them all.

Here is what documentation says…

> RTOWorstCaseMinutes – the longest length of time it would take you to do a restore and get back online. Say you do full backups every night, and log backups every 15 minutes. Your worst case RTO scenario would be if the server went down right before the nightly full backup because you’d have to restore the prior day’s full backup, plus all day long’s transaction log backups. In order to calculate this number, we take the total backup time spent during all of those backups. Technically, this isn’t accurate because your restores could take longer than the backups, especially due to the lack of instant file initialization on the transaction log. This just gives you a rough starting point idea, though.

If you’re wanting to apply the same logic to only a single backup, just check how long it took to take that backup.